# Calling DLL in java: Failed to write core dump

Tags: java, c++, ifstream, coredump

Im trying to build DLL with C++ and then call it from Java.
DLL has one simple functions which should read line from file, make some operations and then save file in binary mode. The code below:

```
    const char* filepath = "C:\\tmp\\test.txt";

std::ifstream input_file;
input_file.open(filepath, std::ios::in));

char line_array[100];

while( !input_file.eof() ) {
    input_file.getline(line_array, sizeof(input_file));
}
input_file.close();

//some operations
//that gives me     
long int arrayToSave[100];

std::ofstream file;
const char* path = "C:\\tmp\\result.txt";
file.open(path, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
if (file.good()) {
    file.write((char*) &arrayToSave, sizeof (arrayToSave));
    file.close();
    res = 1;
}
```

Everything is fine till I try to call it from Java, error below:

```
 {
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000180103fd9, pid=5612, tid=5728

 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
 C  [cygwin1.dll+0xc3fd9]

 Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 C:\workspace\netbeansCAEE\JNAHelloWorldMWrobel\hs_err_pid5612.log
```

}

I have already enabled small memory dumps in Windows 7 options.

Comment: Try to find out what line it is crashing on. Best thing to do here is good ol print statements. Or if you are using an IDE for your C++ development, you can use breakpoints by attaching the C++ IDE to the java process.

Comment: What did it write into the log file? `C:\workspace\netbeansCAEE\JNAHelloWorldMWrobel\hs_err_pid5612.log`

Comment: James; it is crashing on std::ifstream input_file;  (fstream included)

Comment: vojta: here is hs_err_pid612.log content: http://pastebin.com/g7q2LUV3